# Using conditional expressions and incrementing/decrementing a variable

Tags: python

How do I to put the if statement into a conditional expression and how do I increment/ decrement a variable?

```
num_users = 8
update_direction = 3

num_users = 
if update_direction ==3:
   num_users= num_users + 1
else:
   num_users= num_users - 1

print('New value is:', num_users)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. The block after if must be indented

Comment: What is the `num_users =` line supposed to do? If you remove it, your code should be aliright. Unlike in a shell-script, Python doesn't allow you to “set variables to empty”. It's not needed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement would be:

```
num_users = num_users + 1 if update_direction == 3 else num_users - 1
```

For reference, see [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: Thanks dude! I gave you a green check mark for your help. haha

Answer (score 1):

I might be way off the mark and my Python is a bit rusty, but the code looks alright for the problem provided besides the formatting issues pointed out by James K. The if statement you have forms a part of the conditional expression (it is a condition).

Essentially, a conditional expression follows this pattern of:

if(something)-->Do something

The incrementation looks fine. Like James K said, fix the formatting and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())
months = 'January February March April May June July August September October November December'
listOfMonths = months.split(' ')

if (input_month in months and input_day > 1 and input_day < 31):

```
if (input_month == 'March'):
    if input_day < 20:
        print("Winter")
    else:
        print ("Spring")
elif (input_month == 'April'):
    if (input_day < 31):
        print("Spring")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        
elif (input_month == 'May'):
    print("Spring")
    
elif (input_month == 'June'):
    if (input_day < 21):
        print ("Spring")
    elif (input_day > 20 and input_day < 31):
        print("Summer")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        
elif (input_month == 'July' or input_month == 'August'):
    print("Summer")

elif (input_month == 'September'):
    if (input_day < 22):
        print ("Summer")
    elif (input_day > 21 and input_day < 31):
        print ("Autumn")
    else:
        print ("Invalid")
    
elif (input_month == "October"):
    print("Autumn")
    
elif (input_month == "November"):
    if (input_day < 31):
        print ("Autumn")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
        
elif (input_month == "December"):
    if (input_day < 21):
        print ("Autumn")
    elif (input_day > 20):
        print ("Winter")
elif (input_month == 'January'):
    if (input_day < 31):
        print("Winter")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
elif (input_month == "February"):
    if (input_day < 30):
        print ("Winter")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```

else:
print("Invalid")

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add an explanation to how your code answers the question.